# VBA: Pasting clipboard data into the "Find" feature

Tags: vba, excel

I'm an IT noob and have been tasked with creating an Excel macro that will cross-reference an employee number from one sheet to another. After finding a matching employee number it needs to copy the info from that employee (Name,etc) and finally take it to the result page and paste the info.

This is my first time making a VBA macro, or programming in general so bear with me.

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
' 1st attempt
'

Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
Dim S As String
DataObj.GetFromClipboard
S = DataObj.GetText


For x = 1 To 10




Sheets("ad").Select
Cells(11 + x, 7).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("sp").Select
Cells.Find(What:=S, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("Table_GetJobs4[#Headers]").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("Table_GetJobs4[[#Headers],[Company_Code]]"). _
    Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("adtospresult").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Range("A1").Select
Cells.Find(What:="33620", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0 + x, -9).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select

Next x
End Sub
```

Quite simply, I haven't been able to get the clipboard to find function to work. Any help/directions would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `VLOOKUP` to return what you need? I don't think you need VBA for this.

Comment: I will look into VLOOKUP, thanks for the direction.

Comment: No problem. If you need help setting that up, I (or we) would be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to pass the clipboard information to `s` you could just pass the value of the range to `S` like this:

```
s = Cells(11 + x, 7).Value
```

and when you copy it to the other worksheet reverse it.

```
some_range = s
```

Also you don't need to select any worksheets or cells this would be completely valid:

```
Sheets("sp").found_range = Sheets("ad").Cells(11 + x, 7).Value
```

Found range would be the range in the other sheet that you want to paste the first sheet's value.

FYI, http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/train-users-to-follow-best-practices-when-writing-vba-code/ This would be helpful to read over to learn best practices for writing code.  It'll save you in the future when you have to go back and try to decipher what you were doing in you code later down the road.

Comment: Excellent, getting rid of all the "select worksheet" decluttered the code enough for me to make sense of it all again. Got it working! Thanks.